# unable to include css in html in django

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have checked the trajectory 100 times already

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bundles/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all">
```

connect css to html django

Comment: It's really difficult to help without more context, are you loading static assets in your html template {% load static %} ? It would be useful to show your whole html template from a code point of view, also bundles suggest that node may be a factor in compiling your css.

Comment: https://yapx.ru/album/V41HP
here is the link to the photo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.